# Update dictionary value for a particular key with value from iterator of outer loop

Tags: python, json, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list of lists in this format:

```
nrows = ["['Shock pain', 'attack sharp pain']",
         "['bruises', 'lump']",
         "['fever', 'cold', 'Anxiety']",
         "['neck pain', 'headache']"]
```

I want to call an API by passing everytime 1 list at a time from the nrows list. Each list should be passed 1 by 1 to the data dict with key sList and the response should be saved.

The API function is as follows:

```
newres = []
for i in nrows:
    url = "https://testabcd.io"
    data= {
      "sList": i,
      "kList" : ["age"],
    }
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Auth': '0644427814339900'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, json=data)
    newres.append(response.text)

    print(response.text)

    print(newres)
```

Inside the data dict, in `sList`, at each iteration, I want to pass 1 sublist at a time and get the response appended in a list.

The current code has all the response same as I think I am unable to iterate and change the value of the data dict with key sList which is what is expected.

The csv looks like this:

```
['Shock pain', 'attack sharp pain']
['bruises', 'lump']
['fever', 'cold', 'Anxiety']
```

Comment: note that your so called sub-lists are actually strings. Otherwise your code looks good. Make `nrows = [['Shock pain', 'attack sharp pain'], ['bruises', 'lump'], ['fever', 'cold', 'Anxiety'], ['neck pain', 'headache']]`

Comment: You *do not* have a lists of lists. You have a list of strings. How is the `nrows` created?? It looks like you did someting like `nrows.append(str(some_list))`

Comment: @buran, Thanks a lot. It's working now. Any idea how can I change the list of strings to list of lists. I am reading a column from a csv which has all this strings row-wise

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks..nrows is created from a column in a csv. Any idea how can I format that to read as list of lists and not strings

Comment: can you show sample of csv file?

Comment: Also, please don't post same question multiple times https://stackoverflow.com/q/66141163/4046632

Comment: @buran, I have attached a sample from the csv column..kindly check

Comment: do you really have square brackets and single quotes in the csv file/? Because this is not really a csv file. how do you produce the csv file in the first place?

Comment: @buran, it was an export from a pandas dataframe..any idea how can I convert it to the working format?

Comment: The problem is *you don't have a csv*. Were you working with a dataframe with lists in  it? Generally, that is a bad practice. Do you *need* to save it in that format? You should probably just use `pickle`

Comment: I am able to use it now..I removed the [] and ' from the column in the csv and then used split and strip to build the list of lists. thanks for all the help @buran  @ juanpaarrivillaga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file you work with, ***really looks like this***:

```
['Shock pain', 'attack sharp pain']
['bruises', 'lump']
['fever', 'cold', 'Anxiety']
```

you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in order to convert the line from the file into list

```
import requests
from ast import literal_eval

newres = []
url = "https://testabcd.io"
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
           'Auth':'0644427814339900'}

with open("yourfile") as f:
    for line in f:
        data= {"sList": literal_eval(line),
               "kList" : ["age"]}

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        newres.append(response.text)
        print(response.text)
        print(newres)
```

Note:

1. This is not tested.
2. Given that your data comes from non-standard file, where they were exported in bad manner from a dataframe, created unknown how - I would suggest that you seriously reconsider all your workflow and how you manipulate your data.